# Keep both local and remote changes after forgetting to pull

Tags: git, github

I made some changes yesterday on a work computer, which were pushed to remote. Today, I edited some other files from my home computer and upon trying to push to remote, realized that I had forgotten to pull first. How can I make both local and remote in sync while keeping all the changes I've made, both the ones I pushed yesterday, and the ones I've just made on local? I'm working only on the master branch. No other branches.

Comment: `git pull` will handle it for you. It will fetch the new changes from remote and merge them in. Or you can do `git fetch + git rebase` to rebase your local changes on the newly commits fetched from remote.

Comment: I would `git pull --rebase REMOTE BRANCH_NAME` on your home computer. Then push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution would be:

```
git pull
```

This will `fetch` `merge` remote changes with local changes.

If you want a clean commit history it may be worth to go with:

```
git pull --rebase
```

This is the equivalent of `fetch` + `rebase`, which means that your local commits will stack on top of your previous commits.